# Rewriting a file Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

So say I am trying to make a game. The save function of this game works by writing to a file and then reading that when the game is booted up. How can I make it so when the player saves a second time it gets rid of all the old text and replaces that with the new so it can be read again. I'm pretty new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open a file in 'write mode' ('w'), any existing file with the same name will be erased.

```
f = open('savefile', 'w')
```

You can read more about file modes here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Does truncated mean it deletes all the old text? If so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you write to a file in python:

```
writeFile = open("filename.txt", "w")
writeFile.write("some text here\n")
writeFile.write("some more text here\n")
writeFile.close()
```

You are opening the file, writing to it, and then closing it.

In Python, when you write to a file this way, it automatically gets rid of the old text for you when the open() function is called. So you don't need to worry about getting rid of the old next.

When you read from the file:

```
readFile = open("filename.txt", "r")
text = readFile.read()
readFile.close()
```

text will then store all the contents of the file you wrote to.

Alternatively, you may find this easier:

```
readFile = open("filename.txt", "r")
firstLine = readFile.readline()
secondLine = readFile.readline()
readFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still fairly new to programming and have been studying python, so hopefully I am not off base here.

My understanding is that Python has the newer "with" statement that automatically closes files and is a safer update to the previous `open` method. With that said, and writing things as a function you could do things this way:

```
def save_game(save_data):
    with open('save_game.txt', 'w') as save_file:
        save_file.write(save_data)

save_game("I am the data to be saved")
```

Now you can just call the function every time you want to save.